Does Ephesians 4:11 have any implication regarding the Second Coming of Christ?

Eph 4:11-16 11 And He Himself gave some to be apostles, some
prophets, some evangelists, and some pastors and teachers, 12 for
the equipping of the saints for the work of ministry, for the edifying
of the body of Christ, 13 till we all come to the unity of the
faith and of the knowledge of the Son of God, to a perfect man, to the
measure of the stature of the fullness of Christ; 14 that we
should no longer be children, tossed to and fro and carried about with
every wind of doctrine, by the trickery of men, in the cunning
craftiness of deceitful plotting, 15 but, speaking the truth in
love, may grow up in all things into Him who is the head—Christ—
16 from whom the whole body, joined and knit together by what every joint supplies, according to the effective working by which
every part does its share, causes growth of the body for the edifying
of itself in love.

Given there are so many differences in the interpretation of the Bible, it appears there is not yet a unity of knowledge of the Son of God?  How does this play into the Second coming of our Lord? Or does it?

All New Testament teachings that talk about transformed character and behaviour "in Christ" have a twofold meaning. They will apply partially to our current life as individuals and as the church; and they will apply fully and perfectly when Jesus returns.

Verse 13 starts with the phrase:

μέχρι καταντήσωμεν οἱ πάντες...

My translation:

To the degree that the whole group might arrive at...

Where I'm heading is that I don't think Paul has prophesied a future event as much as he's expressing the target to which the leadership aspires to have the church achieve.
μέχρι: You can think of μέχρι as "up to the point of".  Generally, it functions as a preposition.  So, "until" is the simplest way to convey the meaning.  And this is especially true when used in temporal contexts ("until such and such a time").  However, it can function as an adverb, as it does here. LSJ says, "as far as, so used chiefly in Prose..."  And so, it can express an expectation of "the degree" that something would or might occur.  Here, μέχρι is an adverb modifying the verb (which is discussed next).
καταντήσωμεν: καταντάω (come to, arrive; definitely not the common word used for to come) is in the subjunctive.  The subjunctive expresses potential and does not indicate reality.  I would have thought if a future time was being referenced, Paul would have used the future tense in the indicative mood. This is an aorist subjunctive. The subjunctive lends further support to the idea that Paul is referring to something that might occur, that Paul is stating a goal or expectation.  The aorist simply indicates simple action without respect to continuous action or even being in a state (which might be expected here).  So, it's "might arrive".
οἱ πάντες:  πᾶς generally conveys the idea of completeness.  So, articular πᾶς comes pretty close to conveying the idea of "the whole group."
The idea of expectation is further strengthened by Paul expressing growth away from being children.  So, he's talking about maturity.  And, he's talking about the maturity of a group of people. And that should make sense since he's talking about unity.
And lastly, in verse 12, πρὸς τὸν καταρτισμὸν (woodenly, "towards the restoration") is πρὸς with the accusative.  That conveys the idea of "motion or direction towards a place or object." So, again the passage exhorts the achievement of a goal.
So, I don't think this text has anything to say about Christ's second coming or even a prediction of future unity.  It sets an expectation for a desired state we all are to work towards.

Thank you for clarifying.

The unity of the faith is the moment in time when the "fulness of the Gentiles be come in" (Rom 11:25).  It is when the last believer believes during this age of God's grace (Eph 3:1-3), when they will have come to the knowledge of the Son of God, Jesus Christ, by having faith alone in Him alone (Eph 2:8-9).
This indirectly alludes to Christ's second coming to earth for the establishment of His millennial reign (Rev 20:1-6), but more directly addresses when Christ first returns "in the clouds" to gather His now filled body of believers (1 Thes 4:16-18), which is the one true church today, the body of Christ (Eph 1:22-23).
